# how to load latest version of ReactJS app from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, netlify

I am serving react app from a netlify domain. How to serve the most recent deployed version of the app to users who have already loaded previous versions of the app.

Answer (score 1):

one way of achieving this is having a method for fetching the latest version number of the app from server & fethcing it in a useEffect in your root app.js file and if it was different with the version that client is on, then you can delete the browser cache with a reload & the service-worker caches with caches.delete()

so for the comparing part you should consider something like [semver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) (if you are applying the standard) & have a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (
      !!latestClient?.latestVersion &&
      semver.gt(
        semver.coerce(latestClient.latestVersion),
        semver.coerce(application.version)
      )
    ) {
      // here you can have a toast with a button that calls the refresh function onClick
  }, [latestClient]);
```

and your refresh function would be something like this:

```
const refresh = () => {
  if (caches) {
    // deleting service-worker caches
    caches.keys().then((names) => {
      for (const name of names) {
        caches.delete(name);
      }
    });
  }
  // delete browser cache with reload
  window.location.reload();
};
```